Are all time zone identifier strings in 7-bit ASCII?
In other words, can the timezone column in my database have latin1 encoding?
Important to know since the time zone identifiers will be coming from user devices and the database will throw an error if a non-ASCII character is used in the identifier.
On the other hand, having latin1 charset and latin1_bin collation improves the DB performance a bit, especially for indexed columns.
Examples of time zone identifiers: America/Los_Angeles, Australia/Sydney.
Can't seem to find an authoritative source that would say "yes, they are always ASCII".

It depends where they are coming from. Some may be in Unicode, and others may be in non-Latin characters. What are the user devices that you are referring to?

@OldBoy it's iOS and Android. When you say "may be in non-Latin", what is the source of that? After all the identifiers should adhere to some standard. Any ID that is not standard compliant will fail during UPDATE/INSERT and that's OK, I'm not interested in time zone names that can't be identified. But I need to know whether this is the case, i.e. that they all should be in ASCII.

You are asking in the wrong place. We have no idea where this data is coming from, so it is impossible to say what format it will be in.

@OldBoy but I said already it's iOS and Android, what do you mean "we don't know"? How can a timezone identifier on either iOS or Android OS not adhere to the standard?

the IANA tz database builds to ASCII-character-only file names / paths. However, as @OldBoy has commented, if those names / identifiers are coming from some other database, I guess no one can guarantee you that they don't contain non-ASCII chars.

But you are not talking about "timezone identifiers on either iOS or Android OS". You say these items come from user devices. And you have not explained what those devices are or how they are set up.

@OldBoy this is such a meaningless conversation. You either know something about the standardized timezone identifiers or you don't. How do I set up iOS and Android? I buy them, the OS'es come preinstalled with their timezone ID databases. Which is supposed to be standard because otherwise you know, the internet and all the mobile apps in the world will break.

Well you keep ignoring the fact (which I have mentioned more than once), that you have still not explained what are the devices that you are using to get the information from.

I think folks in the question's comments are just being pedantic because you asked about "all" time zone identifiers rather than IANA identifiers.  There have been other schemes, but they are not widely used today.
As for IANA identifiers - yes they are required to be ASCII, and indeed all other requirements keep the characters in the 7-bit numerical range.
From https://data.iana.org/time-zones/theory.html

Use only valid POSIX file name components (i.e., the parts of names other than '/'). Do not use the file name components '.' and '..'. Within a file name component, use only ASCII letters, '.', '-' and '_'. Do not use digits, as that might create an ambiguity with POSIX.1-2017 TZ strings. A file name component must not exceed 14 characters or start with '-'. E.g., prefer America/Noronha to America/Fernando_de_Noronha. Exceptions: see the discussion of legacy names below.

But just to continue being pedantic, IANA identifiers aren't technically a "standard" either.  They're maintained by a community (the tz mailing list), not a standards body (such as ISO, ECMA, IETF, etc.).  They just happen to be ubiquitous enough to be considered a de facto standard.
IANA's role is limited to hosting the mailing list, distributing the tz database, and following RFC6557/BCP175 which guides the procedures for maintaining the tz database.  They don't actually ratify the database as a standard.

Thanks a lot! I suspected that the names would be limited to ASCII to make them file-system safe even on a toaster OS.
